# Many held back PHP 7.4 package updates on Ubuntu 18.04 since 3 weeks

Tags: 18.04, apt, php7

I use PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS in a wp/nginx/mariadb setup. I installed it via Ondrej's main php repo and used/updated it for more than a year without any problem whatsoever. Approximately 3 weeks ago I did an `apt-get update/upgrade` to be up-to-date again, which brought me to PHP V7.4.11, but also led to two problems:

1. I had warnings in PHPmyAdmin concerning deprecated argument lists of
   php functions, which I got rid of by installing a newer stable
   version of PMA (V4.9.7).
2. a growing number of package updates held back week for week, now standing at 23, most of them PHP V7.4 related:

   ```
   php-imagick php7.4-bz2 php7.4-cli php7.4-common php7.4-curl php7.4-fpm php7.4-gd php7.4-json
   php7.4-mbstring php7.4-mysql php7.4-opcache php7.4-readline php7.4-xml php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-zip
   ```

Doing `apt-cache policy` for those reveals that they are all stuck at V7.4.11 although Ondrej provides V7.4.13 candidates already, but I can't figure out what dependency prevents updating them:

```
php7.4-bz2:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-cli:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-common:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-curl:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-fpm:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-gd:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-json:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-mbstring:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-mysql:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-opcache:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-readline:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-xml:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-xmlrpc:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php7.4-zip:
  Installed: 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

php-imagick:
  Installed: 3.4.4-4+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 3.4.4-10+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+4
  Version table:
     3.4.4-10+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.4.4-4+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.4.3~rc2-2ubuntu4.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
     3.4.3~rc2-2ubuntu4 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

What could be the reason for preventing the updates to version 7.4.13, taking into account that updates to `libargon2-0 libxml2 netplan.io` are also held back ?

Do you have some ideas/hints ?

---

*Update 20201208:*

Doing `apt --with-new-pkgs upgrade` displays:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libargon2-1 libicu65 libnetplan0 linux-headers-4.15.0-126 linux-headers-4.15.0-126-generic linux-image-4.15.0-126-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-126-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-126-generic
  motd-news-config php5.6-imagick php7.0-imagick php7.1-imagick php7.2-imagick php7.3-imagick php7.4-imagick php8.0-imagick
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files libargon2-0 libssl1.0.0 libxml2 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic netplan.io php-imagick php7.4-bz2 php7.4-cli php7.4-common php7.4-curl php7.4-fpm php7.4-gd
  php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring php7.4-mysql php7.4-opcache php7.4-readline php7.4-xml php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-zip ubuntu-server
24 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 81.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 368 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Due to the unusual big amount of space needed for the upgrade and the imagick updates for different PHP versions besides V7.4 including V8.0 (! far too *fresh* for my taste) I backed down for the moment/cancelled further upgrading this way. Using `apt-get update/upgrade` updated `libssl1.0.0` and led to the known long list of held back package updates.

---

*Update 20201214:*

Using `apt-get update/upgrade` once again updated a small bunch at first:
`apt apt-utils curl libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 python-apt-common python3-apt` but left the long list of held back package updates unchanged.

---

Thx in advance!

Best regards,
Iunte

Comment: Try running `apt --with-new-pkgs upgrade` and add any logs into the question.

Comment: Done (see above), but backed down before going all-in and used `apt get update/upgrade` again instead.

Thx,
Iunte.

Comment: Using `apt-get update/upgrade` once again updated two packages `openssl libssl1.1` from Ondrej's PPA, but left the long list of held back package updates still unchanged. What can I do about these ? Thx, Iunte.